# "Error: cannot file config find .jshintrc " in cli after cloning the git repo and running grunt

Tags: npm, gruntjs

When i try to run grunt , i am getting error as "cannot file the config file .jshintrc". I tried to install the config dependencies but nothing is working out.Can anyone tell me how to resolve this particular error. Do i need to define any particular rule in my grunt.js file as I believe this should be generated automatically in the root folder after running grunt.
The piece of lines for jshint task in grunt.js is-

```
grunt.initConfig({
    lesslint:{
      src: ['src/']
    },
    jshint: { // configure the task

      all: ['src/app/**/*.js'],
      options: {

          reporter: require('jshint-html-reporter'),

          reporterOutput: 'out/jshint-report.html',
          //force report
          force: false,
          // JS Validation rules are configured in .jshintrc file.
          jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      }
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `.jshintrc` file located in your project?

Comment: Its nowhere located.I believe it should get auto generated at the same place where i have grunt.js.

Comment: You might want to double check that, I don't use jshint but it sounds a little off if it's auto generated but not in your project